i am doing an implementation of qwen_2-vl +byaldi for vision based ocr and hosting it as a stremlit based web app it is not working it keeps crashing
I am working on a Streamlit application that utilizes a multimodal model for image search and text extraction. However, the application frequently crashes during the text extraction process when trying to download the extracted text. Below is the relevant code, along with the steps to reproduce the issue.
requirement.txt
pdf2image

git+https://github.com/huggingface/transformers.git

qwen-vl-utils

#flash-attn

byaldi

qwen_vl_utils

transformers

Steps to Reproduce

Run the Streamlit app with the provided code.
Upload a valid image file (JPG, JPEG, PNG).
Enter a text query in the provided input box.
Click the “Search and Extract Text” button.

import streamlit as st
import base64
from huggingface_hub import notebook_login
from byaldi import RAGMultiModalModel
from transformers import Qwen2VLForConditionalGeneration, AutoTokenizer, AutoProcessor
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
import torch
import re

@st.cache_resource
def load_models():
    RAG = RAGMultiModalModel.from_pretrained("vidore/colpali", verbose=10)
    model = Qwen2VLForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained(
        "Qwen/Qwen2-VL-2B-Instruct",
        torch_dtype=torch.float16,
        device_map="auto",
    )
    processor = AutoProcessor.from_pretrained("Qwen/Qwen2-VL-2B-Instruct")
    return RAG, model, processor

RAG, model, processor = load_models()

st.title("Multimodal Image Search and Text Extraction App")

uploaded_file = st.file_uploader("Choose an image", type=["jpg", "jpeg", "png"])

if uploaded_file is not None:
    image = Image.open(uploaded_file)
    st.image(image, caption='Uploaded Image', use_column_width=True)

    temp_image_path = "uploaded_image.jpeg"
    image.save(temp_image_path)

    @st.cache_data
    def create_rag_index(image_path):
        RAG.index(
            input_path=image_path,
            index_name="image_index",
            store_collection_with_index=True,
            overwrite=True,
        )

    create_rag_index(temp_image_path)

    text_query = st.text_input("Enter your text query")

    if st.button("Search and Extract Text"):
        if text_query:
            results = RAG.search(text_query, k=1, return_base64_results=True)

            image_data = base64.b64decode(results[0].base64)
            image = Image.open(BytesIO(image_data))
            st.image(image, caption="Result Image", use_column_width=True)

            messages = [
                {
                    "role": "user",
                    "content": [
                        {"type": "image"},
                        {"type": "text", "text": "extract text"}
                    ]
                }
            ]

            text_prompt = processor.apply_chat_template(messages, add_generation_prompt=True)

            inputs = processor(
                text=[text_prompt],
                images=[image],
                padding=True,
                return_tensors="pt"
            )

            inputs = inputs.to(model.device)

            with torch.no_grad():
                output_ids = model.generate(**inputs, max_new_tokens=1024)

            generated_ids = output_ids[:, inputs.input_ids.shape[1]:]

            output_text = processor.batch_decode(
                generated_ids, skip_special_tokens=True, clean_up_tokenization_spaces=True
            )[0]

            # Highlight the queried text
            def highlight_text(text, query):
                highlighted_text = text
                for word in query.split():
                    pattern = re.compile(re.escape(word), re.IGNORECASE)
                    highlighted_text = pattern.sub(lambda m: f'<span style="background-color: yellow;">{m.group()}</span>', highlighted_text)
                return highlighted_text

            highlighted_output = highlight_text(output_text, text_query)

            st.subheader("Extracted Text (with query highlighted):")
            st.markdown(highlighted_output, unsafe_allow_html=True)
        else:
            st.warning("Please enter a query.")
else:
    st.info("Upload an image to get started.")

